# Query to create polygon from lines that touches in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon

I am trying to create polygons from a line layer with a spatial query in PostGIS

[image: lines]

The problem is I don't have a lot of information on the lines, only the id of each line and geometry.

Answer (score 1):

check this references and try to build a query:
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Polygonize.html
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Union.html

Comment: Those are the old site links which are no longer being updated.  New site documentation is at http://postgis.net/documentation -  http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html, http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html